# Manejo de datos en SQL

Tags: json, array, base-de-datos

Lamento molestar con esta pregunta, creo que tonta, pero estoy inseguro con el manejo.
Tengo la necesidad de agregar un nuevo valor a una tabla que tiene **propiedades**. El valor que necesito se compone del nombre **antigüedad** y maneja tres tipos de datos distintos.

**Antigüedad**

1. En construccion (boolean)
2. Nuevo (boolean)
3. Años (int)

Es correcto crear este campo como json? o lo más apropiado sería crear una nueva tabla.

Con JSON tengo la duda si esto funciona en MYSQL

```
$table->json('antiguedad')->nullable();
```

Y en el caso de crear la tabla nueva Antigüedad

```
 $table->boolean('construccion');
 $table->boolean('nuevo');
 $table->int('ano');
```

Siempre me quedaría un campo con datos y los otros dos vacíos. Espero no infringir las reglas con esta pregunta, pero necesito de alguien que me de claridad con este tema.

**Edición:**
Basándome en la respuesta de @Betam y @Flor me inclino por crear una nueva tabla:

```
$table->enum('status', ['CONSTRUCCION', 'NUEVO']);
$table->int('ano');
```

**¿Creo que ahora se ve mejor no?**

Comment: La pregunta no versa sobre Laravel una vez dicho eso luce basada en opiniones, por qué considerar json cuando tienes a tu disposición enum ?

Comment: Yo te recomiendo discutir esto mejor en el [chat]

Comment: Yo te recomendaría crear una nueva tabla, para tener un mejor control, es más sano. Dicha tabla `tipo_antiguedad` tendría campo `id, descripción` y luego creas la relación con propiedades.

Comment: Como siempre agradezco la ayuda de ambos. En base a sus comentarios, me inclino por crear una nueva tabla con enum. Aunque tengo una duda respecto al ultimo valor año que es variante. Edite la pregunta a ver si me pueden brindar una idea más. ¡Muchas gracias!